# PETSc configure and building with Intel compilers with cygwin

Tags: windows, build, petsc

i'm trying to configure and build PETSC library to use in my project, in the website of PETSC they recommend cygwin to install the library on windows.
with Intel compilers they provide a file "win32fe.exe" to use it with the configure file.
i follow all the steps from the site:
1-cygwin installation: +python +diffutils+make+gcc+g++
2-run cygwin.bat from VS command prompt and verify "cl" compiler is working from this shell.
3-when i run the configure with win32fe or the help i get the error said:
scripts are in DOS mode
i tried to use dos2unix but it didn't work, and i think this won't work, because there maybe too many files that needs to get transformed from DOS to unix.
grateful for any help.